# How to format numbers as string data-types while exporting to Excel in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, numbers, export-to-excel

In my ASP.NET Web-form Project I have an Event which Export Data (`List<Profit>`) to Excel . I'm using the old fashion way , writing to HTML file with .XLS extenstionmode

`Profit` Entity has some string properties which has numeric data like `"100000561234"`

When I export to Excel , Those Columns appear like `1.00001E+11` in Excel columns, So the user has to Right-Click on Excel column and change format-cell.

Any help appreciated

Comment: How exactly are you doing the export to Excel? Whatever library you're using should have a mechanism to set the style on the cell as you export. If you're doing it the niaeve 'write an HTML file with an .XLS extension' way you're probably be out of luck.

Comment: @Rup, :Yes , I'm Writing to HTML file with .XLS extenstion

Comment: Right - in that case you can either try and get an HTML export from Excel with a cell formatted properly and look for the `mso` attributes that it puts on the cell to indicate the formatting (and declare the mso namespace at the top in the same way too) or you can switch to [one of the Excel generation libraries in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c-sharp) which will have support for formatting cells properly too.

Comment: I found EPPlus to be reliable and easy to use. http://epplus.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply Add the following line before your HTML code, it will resolve the issue. This style sheet will be applied on every cell and no need to format the cell as string manually.

```
Response.Write("<style> TD { mso-number-format:\@; } </style>");
```